# Wordpress - menu that lists page `lis` and also includes the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP, trying to find a way to list the pages for my menu and also include index.php

Here's what I'm using:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>    
        <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=desc&title_li=&depth=2&')?>
        </ul>   
</div><!-- end id:navigation -->
```

Site can be viewed here: http://www.hospiceball.com/wp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do somethig like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>    
            <li><a href='<?php bloginfo('url') ?>'>Home</a></li>
        <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=desc&title_li=&depth=2&')?>
        </ul>   
</div><!-- end id:navigation -->
```

As you can see, I included a new `<li>` element with a like to the home page. That info can be retrieved using the [`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo) function.

**Edit** I have read the Richard's answer and I think it's a better approach. I actually didn't know about the `show_home` option. I'd do in the way I wrote only if I need to customize the anchor of the homepage URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wp_page_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) with the `show_home` option.

```
wp_page_menu('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=desc&title_li=&depth=2&show_home=1')
```